# Azure AD with Symfony 3.4 application

Tags: symfony, azure, active-directory, ldap

I have a Symfony (3.4) application. I manage the users through the FosUserBundle and, for the moment, everything works fine.

Now, I want to use my company's Azure Active Directory to identify my users (and so, use a single sign on).
Unfortunately, I'm a newbie using AD and don't understand what I need to set up the process.

Is LDAP related to Azure AD?
Where can I find documentation to understand the basis?
Do you know where I can find any example about this?

At the moment, I work in local, so I would like to know if it's possible to do it on my localhost?

Have a good day!

Comment: Your question is rather broad, so there is a chance it may get close-voted. But: LDAP is not used with Azure AD, you use the Microsoft Graph API or Azure AD Graph APi via REST calls. And yes, you can work in localhost just fine. As long as your app registration contains the localhost URL in the reply URLS. You can also register a separate app just for development purposes.

Comment: I could not find a super good example for Symfony with quick googling. (Though there was one that uses SAML2. I would recommend you use OpenID Connect/OAuth instead of SAML) I found this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web and this library though: https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure

Comment: Thanks you, I've heard about the Graph API, but didn't understand why it was about graph? I'm kind of surprised there's no "ready-to-use" bundle! I guess it's not as common as I supposed. Thanks for your ansers!

Comment: Both APIs are called "Graph" APIs because essentially they give you access to the organization structure, the users' files, emails etc. (Depending what permissions you require) You can think of the data model offered as a graph. Facebook has a similarly named API :)

Comment: Ok, so I'll try to do it, but it won't be easy at first sight! :'(
Thank you!

Comment: Hello Alexandre, I'm in the same situation, did you find how to do ? I would like to use the [Azure Active Directory Provider for OAuth 2.0 Client](https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure) but I don't know where to put the code... Should I create a route for login and put the code in a `loginAction()` function inside a Controller ?

Comment: Hello Eve, I didn't manage to do it at that time. But I think the TheNetworg /
oauth2-azure is a good tool to do it. This isn't a bundle, so you will have to write some code. Maybe I'm wrong, but you could also use https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html

Comment: Ok thank you Alexandre, maybe I found something interesting, the [OAuth2 client bundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) from KNP University for Symfony, it uses the TheNetworg OAuth2 Azure bundle.